# Swift 4save recorded video to photo album

Tags: xcode, swift4, avkit

This is my first attempt at recording and saving a video with AVKit etc. and although I am able to display and record a video with the method:

```
 @IBAction func recordVideo(_ sender: Any) {

        // Check the camera is available
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerController.SourceType.camera){
            // present the camera
            controller.sourceType = .camera
            controller.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeMovie as String]
            controller.delegate =  self
            present (controller,animated: true, completion: nil)
        }else{
            // No camera available so show alert
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Oops!", message: "Can't access the camera!", preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Give up", style: .default, handler: nil))
            self.present(alert, animated: true)

            uploadButton.isHidden = true
        }
    }
```

I am having trouble saving the recorded video to the photo album. When I step through the code it jumps from the 'guard' line into the 'else' block and simply returns. So for some reason it's not able to assign anything to 'mediaType'

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo vidInfo: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]){

        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

        guard let mediaType = vidInfo[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.mediaURL] as? String,
            mediaType == (kUTTypeMovie as String),
            let url = vidInfo[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.mediaURL] as? URL,
            UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum(url.path)
            else {
                return
        }

        // Handle a movie capture
        UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(url.path, self, nil, nil)
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `vidInfo[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.mediaURL]` can't be at the same time a `String` and a `URL`.

Comment: I see, how would I re-write that to make it work, I was following the example on [link](https://youtu.be/co6IIGGrjqc) where it appears to be working.

Comment: According to the doc: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimagepickercontroller/infokey/1619149-mediaurl it's an URL, I think you are looking for `mediaType` (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimagepickercontroller/infokey/1619121-mediatype), so mediaType should be check with that key.